# Sheaf Associated with a presheaf as an inverse image

Tags: sheaf-theory

My question essentially comes from EGA I (the Springer version), of the item (3.5.6) of the Préliminaires.

The ideia is that given a presheaf of a topological space $X$ going to a category $C$, we can express the sheaf associated to it, via the [direct image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_image_functor) of the inverse image through the identity function $1_X = I:X\to X$, give that the latter exists.

\begin{equation}
    \tilde{\mathcal{F}} = I_*I^{-1}(\mathcal{F}) = I^{-1}\mathcal{F}
\end{equation}

Maybe I'm missing something out, but it is not obvious for me why $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$ is a sheaf. I'll give some more details:

Firstly, the direct image through the identity function is, of course, $\mathcal{F}$ itself (justifying the second equality above). You'll see why I made the distinction later.

Secondly, the inverse image is defined as the [left adjoint](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor) to the direct image, so we have a natural bi-isomorphism

\begin{align}
    \hom(I^{-1}\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}) &\xrightarrow{\cong} \hom(\mathcal{F}, I_*\mathcal{G})\ \ \ (= \hom(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}) )\\
    u &\mapsto u^\flat
\end{align}

Using $\mathcal{G} = I^{-1}\mathcal F$ and using $u = 1_\mathcal{F}$ we have a natural morphism $\rho:\mathcal F \to \tilde{\mathcal F}$ satisfying the following unviersal property: for every $v: \mathcal F \to \mathcal G$ there exists a unique $v^\sharp: \tilde{\mathcal F} \to \mathcal G$ such that $v$ is the composite

\begin{equation}
    v: \mathcal F \xrightarrow{\rho} \tilde{\mathcal F} \xrightarrow{v^\sharp} \mathcal G.
\end{equation}

OBS: the aplication $v \mapsto v^\sharp$ is the inverse of $u \mapsto u^\flat$.

This is the universal property that we would want the sheaf associated to $\mathcal F$ to [satisfy](https://randommathgenerator.com/2016/12/28/sheafification/) (Well, actually if we restrict ourselves only to $\mathcal G$ that are sheaves ). **However** we need $\tilde{\mathcal F}$ to be a sheaf in the first place (for example, $\mathcal F$ has the same universal property, but it is not its sheafification).

Okay, so there are some equivalent ways of proving that a presheaf is a sheaf. We most certainly will need to use some of the properties of [adjoint functors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor) to prove this.

I thought I had solved this since [left adjoint preserves colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoints+preserve+%28co-%29limits), so we would have something like this

\begin{equation}
    \tilde{\mathcal F}(\injlim U_\lambda) = \projlim{\tilde{\mathcal F}U_\lambda}
\end{equation}

which is the sheaf condition (for cocomplete category $C$, but i would be completely satisfied with this)!

However we have that the *inverse image functor is left adjoint to the direct image functor* as functors between $pSh(X)$, and not (necessarily (I think)) we have that $\psi^{-1}\mathcal F$ is left adjoint to $\psi_*\mathcal F$ as functors of $Open(X)^\text{op} \to C$ (which would be enough by the [above argument](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoints+preserve+%28co-%29limits)).

Any help on this? I guess by looking around there is another (more concrete) description of the inverse image of a sheaf, but I'm avoiding this. EGA seems only to mention this here, so I think this is doable using only the abstract nonsense definition.

Comment: As far as I know, if you have a map $f: X \to Y$ of topological spaces, then the inverse image of a presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $Y$ is defined as the sheafification of the presheaf $$ U \mapsto \varinjlim_{V \supset f(U) \text{open}}\mathcal{F}(V). $$ So $I^{-1}(\mathcal{F})$ is by definition a sheaf. And then the direct image of any sheaf is a sheaf.

Comment: Well EGA defines it as the left adjoint to direct image as I mentioned in the question. It uses this definition to define sheafification in the first place! So this is not very iluminating. The mistery is how it just plainly states that the presheaf described above is a sheaf with no other commentary, and how would you prove such statement given what was said about inverse images.

Comment: The inverse image functor I described in my comment is left adjoint to the direct image functor. Also, doesn't EGA simply define the sheafification functor as the left adjoint to the inclusing functor of the category of sheaves into the category of presheaves?

Comment: The definition of inverse image in EGA is not standard any more : it is the left adjoint of the composite $U\circ \psi_*$ where $U$ is the forgetful functor from sheaves to presheaves. Put like this, if $\psi$ is the identity, so is $\psi_*$ and the inverse image is indeed the sheafification.